# Deactivate users using JIRA SOAP API

Tags: php, soap, jira

I am trying to **deactivate users** in JIRA  using **php** script and **JIRA SOAP Api**.

I googled it for and got **deleteUser()** method for deleting users 
but **unable** to find how to make user **inactive** instead of deleting the user.

Is there any way to deactivate the user using SOAP api?

Please find the code below which deletes the user:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
session_start();
$soapClient = new SoapClient("http://jira.abc.com/jira/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl");
$token = $soapClient->login('abc', 'abc') or die('Username/Password is not correct!');
$result = $soapClient->deleteUser($token, 'testUser');
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you look to the available methods, such at https://www.wsdltophp.com/Wsdls/49736a5cd804750495b9d411893516be/jira-1-0-1-1-1-1-1-1-0-0?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have gone through the link but not getting how it will be implemented to get the job done. Can you please suggest?